# Internet check is failure in Iphone

Tags: ios, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

In my sencha touch application i am unable to retrieve internet connection, but device able to access the wifi when i try to surf through browser. In android its working fine, but in ios the connection is **undefined**. I am using same wifi for both devices.

```
 checkConnection: function() {
        if (Ext.os.is('android') || Ext.os.is('iphone')) {
            alert("connection"+Ext.device.Connection.isOnline());
            alert('Your connection type is: ' + Ext.device.Connection.getType());
            return Ext.device.Connection.isOnline();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using phonegap/cordova? If so then why don't you use the cordova network API directly? I.e. try something like

```
checkConnection: function() {
    if (Ext.device) {
        return Ext.device.Connection.isOnline();
    } else {
        return navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please note navigator.network.connection should be used below cordova 2.3. In newer versions you should use navigator.connection. See documentation for details.